# how to get rows which have max value2 when value1 is equal using django queryset

Tags: sql, django

for example

```
rowid    value1   value2
1        1         2
2        1         3
3        2         4
```

then select (1,1,3) and (3,2,4) because row1 and row2 have the same value1, and value2 of row2 is bigger than value2 of row1

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sql this is a simple aggregation query using `group by` and `min()`/`max()`

```
select 
    min(rowid) as rowid
  , value1
  , max(value2) as value2
from t
group by value1
```